# First Fundamental Forms - alternative definition

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, curves

In the following picture, $U \subset \Bbb{R}^m$ is an open set, $f: U \to \Bbb{R}^{m+n}$ is a parameterization, $\gamma: I \to U$ is a smooth curve and $\tilde{\gamma} = f \circ \gamma$.

[image]

The function
$$g_{ij}(x) = \delta_{mn}\frac{\partial f^m}{\partial x_i}(\gamma(t))\frac{\partial f^j}{\partial x_j}(\gamma(t))$$
is the First Fundamental Form.

I think the index $m$ and $n$ are just a bad notation and, certainly $1/2$ is a misprint. My question is about the summation of the inner product and the chain rule. By definition of inner product
$$\langle \frac{d}{dt}\tilde{\gamma}(t), \frac{d}{dt}\tilde{\gamma}(t) \rangle = \sum_{i,j = 1}^{m+n}\delta_{ij}\frac{d}{dt}\tilde{\gamma}_i(t)\frac{d}{dt}\tilde{\gamma}_j(t)$$
and
$$\frac{d}{dt}\tilde{\gamma}_i(t) = \frac{d}{dt}(f_i \circ \gamma)(t) = \sum_{r=1}^{m} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_r}f_i(\gamma(t))\frac{d}{dt}\gamma_r(t).$$
So, I don't know why the equality on the picture is true.

Comment: The two equations you have written down perfectly fit with the expression under the square root. I don't see any problem – could you say more, maybe?

Comment: @PawełCzyż I cannot see why $\sum_{i,j}^{m+n}$ of the inner product does not appear in the square root.

Comment: It appears – in index notation you sum over repeated indices ($m,n,i,j$).